# Which maven dependency to use for google contact V3 in spring boot java project?

Tags: spring-boot, google-contacts-api, maven-dependency

I am trying to integrate google contact API for my project but I cannot find the google contact V3 maven dependency for accessing the ContactsService class.

I tried the gdata-core dependency through which the build gets failed as my project also contains the calendar dependency and the Gmail dependancy so I don't know which dependency to use? Below down I have mentioned the gdata core dependency  I tried to use and the gdata contact dependency both dont get compiled

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdata-contacts-3.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.5</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdata-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.1</version>
</dependency>
```